# How to filter Recycleview by ignoring case?

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from Recyclerview I am adding the searchview filter in my app, but when I search capital and lower text the no result found I think may be causing a problem on the string, please help me with this!!

```
private void search(final String s){
            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("name").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");


        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        final Contacts contacts = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Contacts.class);
                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        assert contacts != null;
                        if (!contacts.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            arrayList.add(contacts);
                        }
                    }


                 MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplication(), arrayList, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                   public void onItemClick(Contacts item) {
                            //Toast.makeText(FindFriendsActivity.this, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String visit_user_id=item.getUid();
                    Intent profileIntent=new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                     profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id",visit_user_id);
                      startActivity(profileIntent);
                        }
                    });

                    FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    //onStart();
                    FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FindFriendsActivity.this));
                    adapter.startListening();
                    FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

I get the from query and firebase data snapshot but when I search capital and lower text on searchview the no result found how can I ignore the case problem in my code

Answer (score 2):

You can use equals Ignore case for that...this is the string function for ignoring case.

```
if (!contacts.getName().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) // something like this..
{
    arrayList.add(contacts);
}
```

You can try with `.toLowerCase()` on your username and the text you are getting from search view and check.... for searching on username...

I consider that you might be getting all the data in your contacts class's object.. then you just have to check the entered string from search view in your get filter method like above and `.contains` will check if entered string is present or not... if you want you can also do `.startsWith(s.toString().toLowerCase())` if you want to search the name starting with the string entered in the search view..

Comment: not working   How to filter recyclerview by ignoring case?

Comment: you are asking for ignore case and this function works...but please check what are you searching for... example if you are searching for name or anything else then you have to include that in your if statement.

Comment: i have search only user name

Comment: then instead of getUid you should use getUserName or the field you have assigned for user name ..you are searching on a wrong field that's why search is not working...

Comment: Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("name").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");

Comment: i am only get the username

Comment: can i use String name=contacts.getName().toString();

Comment: how to use please help

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase,
                             int toffset,
                             String other,
                             int ooffset,
                             int len)
```

ignoreCase : if true, ignores case when comparing characters.

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String str, String searchStr)     {
        if(str == null || searchStr == null) return false;

        final int length = searchStr.length();
        if (length == 0)
            return true;

        for (int i = str.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str.regionMatches(true, i, searchStr, 0, length))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert both of them to same case using toLowerCase() or toUpperCase():

```
 if (!contacts.getUid().toLowerCase().equals(firebaseUser.getUid().toLowerCase())) {
     arrayList.add(contacts);
 }
```

Comment: i have the answer but i cant implement

Comment: if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhone().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }

Comment: but how to using this method on datasnapshot bcos i have not string